# Basic comparison always returns false

Tags: java, intellij-idea, static-members

I have a class definition like below. I want it to be a singleton.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static MyClass sInstance;
    public static final int STATUS_CONSTANT = 0;
    public int myProperty = 0;

    public static MyClass get() {
        if (sInstance==null) {
            sInstance= new MyClass();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

When using it, JetBrains IdeaJ warns me that the comparison always returns false...

```
MyClass myClass = MyClass.get();
if (myClass.myProperty == MyClass.STATUS_CONSTANT) {
    ...
}
```

...whereas, it doesn't say anthing if I make it this way:

```
if (MyClass.get().myProperty == MyClass.STATUS_CONSTANT)
```

I did not get why it's angry about the first method!? In either way, it should be referencing the same static field (sInstance).

Comment: what version of intellij are you using? I cant reproduce this in v13.x

Comment: I can't see any error there. Both conditions return true to me.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct way of initializing "public int myProperty = 0;" ?? And also have a private constructor, else how will it be a singleton I wonder. Implement the clone method and return null to make sure the object produced is not clonable

Comment: Which Java version use your IDE?

Comment: @SanyamGoel As long as he doesn't try to get instances of MyClass using new instead MyClass.get it will work as a singleton but it is true that making the Constructor private make it impossible.

Comment: @SanyamGoel, i just tried to give out portion about the problem. Then I shouldn't have mention about its being singleton, you're right.

Comment: @UmeshPatil I thought the same, that's why I'm here...

Comment: This looks like a bug in IDEA, but I cannot reproduce it. Could you please report a bug to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard and attach a standalone code sample which demonstrates this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't see any problem with your condition so I copied your code into a NetBeans project and I didn't get any alert like that so I decided to run your code:

```
MyClass myClass = MyClass.get();
if (myClass.myProperty == MyClass.STATUS_CONSTANT) {
    System.out.println("OK");
}
```

And it prints "OK" so there is a case where the condition is not false.

I can see there are some reported bug in the "always false condition" IntelliJ checker:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91390

Comment: Well, it seems like a bug, similar but not the same as you linked.